# How to find the position in Listview when the screen on touch mode?

Tags: android, listview, listener

I work on an application for blind people and the difficulties

I am having that, when the user **swipe** one finger from **top screen to bottom** on a **listview**, on which ever item finger goes on while the finger moves I want to find out the **position** basically details in the item.

This is not a **onitemclicklistener**! the finger moves on the items so the screen goes on **touch mode**. Is there any listener or around way of finding out the postion of the item?

your helps and comments much appreciated.

Comment: I'm not sure whether there exists some listener like that or not. But if you know your item's height -which i assume, yes- you can calculate it. Just catch touch event onTouchListener of listview and get Y position, then find where it is.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a wild suggestion, not tested:

1. In `getView()` of the listview adapter, use `View.setTag(Object)` to attach any custom data to the view.
2. Set an `OnTouchListener()` to each view before returning.
3. In the `OnTouchListener()` `onTouch(View, MotionEvent)`, you get the view, and you can do `view.getTag()` to get the custom data that you attached.

Comment: this sounds helpful. but could you be more specific? I don't use custom adapter I use SimpleAdapter.

Comment: Oh. Then I think you will have to use a custom adapter and override the `getView()` method.